# dispatch_async UI Update Crashes app while editing textField?

Tags: ios, crash, grand-central-dispatch

[image]I created a sample iphone application. I am getting two inputs from user using Two textfields. My application receive udp data from server and check the data with these two textfields. When data matches found showing an alert to user, everything works fine. When i click textfield and edit some values, while application receive data my application get crashed some times. Crash occurs occasionally. Crash line shows at main.m file. I added exception break point .

-NOTE : UDP Receive only stops when application terminated. I am using dispatch_async for udp receive.

Can anyone help me thanks?

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread
    //UDP Receive
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
        // Data checking with textfields and update UI
    });
});
```

Comment: Unless you provide details about the crash (error and relevant code), it is nearly impossible to help.

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: It doesnot show any crash log on my iPhone.

Comment: You can see the crash log in Xcode.

Comment: Add an Exception Breakpoint to get some info a little earlier and post what you find.